# Campaign insights return null Facebook Marketing API

Tags: php, facebook, api

I am grabbing all of the campaigns associated with a user and trying to get insights for the campaigns. I get the campaigns just fine but when I try to get the insights it always returns null. I have tried changing the days and different fields.

```
$api = Api::instance();

$id = trim($_POST['actid']);

$account = new AdAccount($id);

$fields = array(
    CampaignFields::NAME,
    CampaignFields::ID,
);

$campaigns = $account->getCampaigns($fields);



$cleanArray = [];
foreach ($campaigns as $campaign) {

    $campFields = array(
    AdsInsightsFields::CPC,
);

$params = array(
    'time_range' => array(
    'since' => (new DateTime("-1 day"))->format('Y-m-d'),
    'until' => (new DateTime('NOW'))->format('Y-m-d'),
    ),
);

$campInsights = $campSelect->getInsights($campFields, $params);
$innerArray = [];
array_push($innerArray,$campaign->{CampaignFields::NAME});
array_push($innerArray,$campaign->{CampaignFields::ID});
array_push($innerArray,$campInsights->{AdsInsightsFields::CPC});
array_push($cleanArray,$innerArray);
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($cleanArray);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was a scope issue as I still needed to iterate through the object as an array. Posting this to help others.

```
foreach($campInsights as $insights){
    $cpc = $insights->{AdsInsightsFields::CPC}.PHP_EOL;
    $clicks = $insights->{AdsInsightsFields::WEBSITE_CLICKS}.PHP_EOL;
}
```

After I looped through the object, I was able to grab the values.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `getInsights` returns an iterator, as requests to gather insights can return a set of results.

If you're sure it will only return a single result, you can just access `$campInsights[0]`.

You also have an error in your code in this line, as `$campSelect` is not defined:

```
$campInsights = $campSelect->getInsights($campFields, $params);
```

It should be:

```
$campInsights = $campSelect->getInsights($campFields, $params);
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that. It was actually a scope issue. Ill post my answer to help anyone else as their documentation is not that good.